# USB devices only recognized after I login

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, usb, mouse

I'm experiencing some troubles after upgrade 11.10 final version... In the matter of fact, I never had troubles using the devices, with the upgrade, but I formatted the notebook, and made a Clean Ubuntu Install and now I have this strange behavior of my OS.

I have a notebook a little old, but good enough to run Ubuntu cool. But after the 11.10 my USB devices like Keyboard, mouse, and an external Hard Drive was running fine, but now I can't login with the keyboard or have any response of mouse movements or clicking until I login in LightDM in the notebook keyboard. Only after login I can use my USB devices normally...

Have anyone a tip, or fix to this?

Is this some kind of bug?

Anyone else is in the same situation? Or passed through it?

Since now, thank you for the attention.

Comment: Oh i've searched in the Askubuntu but i couldn't find no problem like mine.

I'm not a completelly lazy bastard. :D

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/807291

I did not see a fix in the bug report(s)

he "work around" seems to be to unplug the mouse/keyboard and plug them in again.

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not be for everyone, here's what i did to solve this problem. I put a PS2 keyboard and mouse into my computer. It works just fine.

Additionally, i installed a Synergy client on my Ubuntu, so that after i log in, i use the shared mouse and keyboard.

I hope this helps.

Love and peace,

Joe